# which of the following inequalities must always be true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w = u+iv$ and, $z = x+iy$ be complex numbers such that $w^2 = z^2+1$.
Then which of the following inequalities must always be true?

(a) $x \le u$
(b) $y^2 \le v^2$
(c) $v^2 \le y$

Tried to calculate the problem using the given condtion but failed to get any conclusion.

Can I get some help please?

Comment: Are you sure about part (c)? I can see that the first two parts cannot be true.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Could $u$ be negative and $x$ positive?

Could $v$ be $0$ and $y$ nonzero?

Could $y$ be negative?